# Determine Most Frequent Font Size from Histogram

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram, signal-processing

How can we find the most frequent font size present in a document image using the histogram of black components? Below is my code for displaying the histogram of my image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os.path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image_counter = 1

    while True:

        if not os.path.isfile(str (image_counter) + '.png'):
            break

        image_path = str(image_counter) + '.png'
        image = plt.imread(image_path)


        #Display Histogram
        #print(image)
        #print(image.ravel())
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(image.ravel(), bins = 256)
        plt.title('Image Patch # ' + str(image_counter))
        plt.xlabel('Grey Value')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency')
        window = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
        window.canvas.set_window_title('Histogram')
        plt.show()

        image_counter = image_counter + 1
```

Comment: You can't. Few letters in a big font size could have the same amount of black/gray as more letters in a smaller font size. Also depends on each letter, since they all have a variable distribution of pixels.

Comment: @TA --> Will vertical projection profile determine the most frequent font size?

Comment: Might perform better, but you will still have issues e.g. with different line lengths or different page layout.